# I want to capture Analytics for all posts under a Category on my WordPress Blog using Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, blogs, google-tag-manager

I have created a Custom Javascript Variable to Capture the category of the Post (Only one Category per Post). This is the code for the variable.

```
function()
{
      if (document.getElementById("categoryofthepost"))
      {
             var element = document.getElementById("categoryofthepost");
         var category = element.textContent;
        return category;
      }

}
```

On the Google analytics Interface I get the correct Metrics for the analytics but the custom Dimension defined as "Posts by Categories" does not show the Name of the Category.

for Example in the below image second Page **/en/solutions/cloud** must show the Category name **cloud** but instead it shows the following output.

[Image Screenshot of my Google Analytics Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5PEw.png)

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think there is enough info to help you. My first guess would be that you use a wrong index for your dimension and send a different value than you intend to the "Posts by Category" dimension. The basic idea you are following is sound, but there is not enough info to debug implementation details.

Comment: Hi Erik,

Thanks for the Reply. I went back and checked the index of the custom variable and also doubled checked the variable name to the name of the custom Dimension attached to it but it still didn't work. GTM debugger shows that my Tag is returning the desired value but on the analytics interface it returns a gibberish value. Can you help me out with that? Or can you tell me what more information you would need to help me out with this? I am in a tight spot here and would really appreciate the help.